# Android App : Managing user account information without a server

Tags: android, database

I am thinking about the design of an android application which will need to create user accounts and have some information about the app users. While researching in the internet and the developer site, I got the impression that to maintain the database , you have to have a server.

What if I don't want to maintain the account information in my own server (i.e. I am not willing to maintain my own server for this), what options do I have and what will be their drawbacks (if any).

If there is no other choice but to use a server, then can I get suggestions as to how can I modify my design so that I don't have to use a server.

I am a novice at this field, so I would appreciate advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how can I use it so that the above conditions are satisfied, it would be helpful if you can explain this or atleast provide a link which can help.

Answer (score 0):

Create external database file with **credential table** in this table create appropriate columns like username,password etc..here if you have registered users then store those users details in **credential table**.Finally copy that database in assests folder then using SqliteOpenHelper class copy that external database to phone memory.Here you need to maintain **registration page** with conditions.If the user completes the **registrations procedure** with your conditions then store his/her details in **credential table**.When user wants to **login** to the App please check the **username** and **password** in **credential table**.

Comment: This kind of ties the user to only using their device. If they wanted to login to the app from another device there would be no way of retrieving their data.