# Creating Accounts in an Android App

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-account

I am wanting to make an android app that will have user accounts. The app is like a contact manager and messaging app in one. Each contact will have a Name, a Number, and a password. Basically, the user will select from a spinner menu the contact name. The user will then enter the message. When the send button is clicked, the user will be asked to enter the password required to send to that specific number. The contact details will need to be kept private.

I have done some Google searches, however this is the closest i have come to finding anything:
[Android App : Managing user account information without a server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9765967/android-app-managing-user-account-information-without-a-server)

I am new to Android programing so any help would be much appreciated.

P.S. Sorry if this is somewhat vague

Comment: is the app is used by only some group of users at one place or remotely contacting with all users?

Comment: the app will be used on one phone to contact other numbers there will however be more than one person using the phone, but not all users are allowed to contact the same numbers

Comment: The best way is keep the admin and users for this app. the first created user is admin and rest are users. so admin have the choice to add contacts and users like that..

Comment: Thanks, do you have any code example or links to tutorials on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways -

1. Online Mode - Write some application in PHP, MYSQL for user account management,etc. and call the approrpate URL for user authentication and other actions. You can use LAMP or WAMP stack for the same. You will need to host this application on server (public hosti9ng service or into your organization's server)
   You may use Android's SMS APIs for sending the messages.
2. Offline Mode -  Use local local database (e.g. Sqllite) for user authentication, etc. 
   But you will need to explicitly take actions to sync all the user accounts.

regards,
dattatray.

Comment: I would prefer the Offline mode. Do you have any examples or link to tutorials on how i would do this?

Comment: I think you will first need to study the Android SQLite Database programming. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement.

Do as like `this....`

You need to maintain two types of users say `Admin` and `users`.

The person who installs the app in mobile and registered first will be the `Admin` to the app.
And remaining are the `users` for the App.

Admin have the right to create users and he have the rights to do all the front end work.

And if you need maintain sessions do study about [`How to maintain sessions in Android using shared  preference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173287/may-mainting-the-session-using-shared-preference-in-android)

This concept is very very important for your App. so be perfect in this!!!

Comment: first of do paper work and search for your requirement in google. you will be success. good luck!